# cmark error is coming when installing pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, cmark

[my podfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaRGF.png)

When im installing my podfile I got an error as

```
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
echo `pwd`
sed -i '' 's/include <\(cmark.*\)>/include "\1"/' src/cmark.h
mkdir -p build; cd build && cmake -G Xcode ..
```

So I tried to install cmake using terminal I installed it but now im getting the below error.

[cmake version shown in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFbNn.png)

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (3.2.1)
Installing DTCoreText (1.6.21)
Installing DTFoundation (1.7.13)
Installing GZIP (1.2.2)
Installing HPGrowingTextView (1.1)
Installing MatrixKit (0.8.3)
Installing MatrixSDK (0.11.3)
Installing OLMKit (2.3.0)
Installing Realm (3.7.6)
Installing cmark (0.24.1)
[!] /bin/bash -c 
set -e
echo `pwd`
sed -i '' 's/include <\(cmark.*\)>/include "\1"/' src/cmark.h
mkdir -p build; cd build && cmake -G Xcode ..

/Users/mac1/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/cmark/0.24.1-ec027
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.0.10001145
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/mac1/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/cmark/0.24.1-ec027/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/Users/mac1/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/cmark/0.24.1-ec027/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.12.3/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /Users/mac1/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/cmark/0.24.1-ec027/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/xcodebuild" "-project" "CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE.xcodeproj" "build" "-target" "cmTC_1e4ec" "-configuration" "Debug"
    2018-10-17 11:18:22.272 xcodebuild[2991:68431] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID 8B9F56A7-4D8B-41AA-A65D-D4906CDF1539 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/ClangFormat.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
    Build settings from command line:
        TOOLCHAINS = com.apple.dt.toolchain.XcodeDefault

    2018-10-17 11:18:23.814 xcodebuild[2991:68451]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from e8c3d7ea8e6dddb6703f918e871eea481e436c21 was NULL
    2018-10-17 11:18:23.934 xcodebuild[2991:68512]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from e8c3d7ea8e6dddb6703f918e871eea481e436c21 was NULL
    Prepare build
    note: Using legacy build system

    === BUILD TARGET cmTC_1e4ec OF PROJECT CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

    Check dependencies
    target specifies product type 'com.apple.product-type.tool', but there's no such product type for the 'iphoneos' platform

    ** BUILD FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
        Check dependencies
    (1 failure)




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)
```